# How can I stop and resume the observable in Android?

Tags: android, observable, rx-android, rx-java2

```
    Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                //TODO
            }

        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
```

So I have this piece of code. I would like to start emitting values when the onResume() method being executed, and stop it when onPause() method being executed. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using those methods? Try digging into the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onresume)

Comment: Whether your "observing" or not with a hot observable it will be emitting items, the difference being your subscription life cycle.  Just subscribe and unsubscribe when you want to be notified - there should be no pause or resume of the observable itself.

Comment: Its ok, but I need to stop it when the activity is in background, and RESTART emitting it when its active.